# Lmer failue to converge in random slope linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model

I am fitting a random slope liner mixed model with rank as the DV and season and position as fixed effects. I also have a random intercept for season and a random slope for season*round.

```
Model1.0<-lmer(Rank~Season+Position +(1|Season)+(1+Season|Round),     
data=mydata, REML=T)
```

The model without the random slope worked fine however, I get some warning messages when the model is run with the season*round random slope component.

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.53894 (tol = 0.002,component1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

I attempted to rescale the variables in mydata with the following code (I found it online after searching these warning messages)

```
numcols<-grep("^c\\.",names(mydata))
mydatas<-mydata
mydatas[,numcols]<-scale(mydatas[,numcols])
Model1.0s<-update(Model1.0,data=mydatas)
```

After running the model again with this updated data, R still returned the same warning messages. The rescaling appeared to work so I'm not sure why R is still requesting that I rescale my data. Any suggestions?

In regards to the first warning message, after searching this and other forums I tried different optimizers ("bobyqa" and "Nelder Mead") but neither seemed to work. Are there any other suggestions for getting around the failure to converge warning?

I am using the lmer package and have 104982 rows of data. There are 13 seasons in the analysis and approx. 286 rounds (~22 per season).

Comment: `(Season|Round)` specifies that the effects of `Season` vary across levels of `Round` which seems to be a bit over-parametrized. Take this one notch down to: `(1|Season/Round)`. This would be equivalent to `(1|Season) + (1|Season:Round)`. Try it and see how this behaves. Also consider using: `(1|Season)+(0+Season|Round)` so you do not estimate correlations between the slopes and the intercepts. (And avoid using code off the Internet. Just scale your variables using `scale` you should be fine; `scale` just z-transforms the variable (ie. unit variance and mean zero))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Season|Round)` specifies that the effects of `Season` vary across levels of `Round` which seems to be a bit over-parametrized for this particular problem given the numerical issues reported. A potential remedy is to lower the number of estimated parameters to: `(1|Season/Round)`. This would be equivalent to `(1|Season) + (1|Season:Round)` and correspond to a nested design. As an alternative one might also consider using: `(1|Season)+(0+Season|Round)` where in this case the model will not estimate correlations between the slopes and the intercepts.

Finally as the error message suggests you might want to $z$-transform your original features to unit variance and mean zero. That can be easily done using `scale` so your new `Position` for example would be `mydata$PositionZ <- scale(mydata$Position)`. Notice that $z$-transforming your variable will change the interpretation of your $\beta$ coefficients. One unit higher of the $z$-transformed variable will correspond to one standard deviation higher in the original domain of the variable. Finally notice that $z$-transformation sense only for continuous variables; you can always $z$-transform discrete variables but the scaling will be meaningless. :D